# SpringBootTest does not roll back

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

(Although, there are plenty of similar questions I was not able to find the solution among them).

Why `@Transactional` annotation with `@SpringBootTest` works and rolls back nicely when I use `DAO` directly, but does not work when I test with `TestRestTemplate`?

**tl;dr**

Entity

```
@Entity
public class ToDoItem {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  @NotNull @Column(unique = true)
  private String title;

  public ToDoItem() {}

  public ToDoItem(String title) { this.title = title;}
  // getters, setters, etc.
```

Repository

```
public interface ToDoRepository extends CrudRepository<ToDoItem, Long> {}
```

Application

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/todos")
public class ToDoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToDoApp.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ToDoRepository toDoRepository;

    @GetMapping
    ResponseEntity<?> fetchAll() { return ok(toDoRepository.findAll()); }

    @PostMapping()
    ResponseEntity<?> createNew(@RequestBody ToDoItem toDoItem) {
        try {
            toDoRepository.save(toDoItem);
            return noContent().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I create two tests which do basically the same: store some to-do items in in-memory database and check if size has increased:

Repository test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class ToDoRepoTests {

    @Autowired
    private ToDoRepository toDoRepository;

    @Test
    void when_adding_one_item_then_success() {
        toDoRepository.save(new ToDoItem("Run tests"));
        assertThat(toDoRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1);
    }

    @Test
    void when_adding_two_items_then_success() {
        toDoRepository.saveAll(List.of(
                new ToDoItem("Run tests"), new ToDoItem("Deploy to prod")));
        assertThat(toDoRepository.findAll()).hasSize(2);
    }
}
```

Then I create similar test that does exactly the same thing but via REST API (This one does not work and fails with `Unique index or primary key violation`):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ToDoApp.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
class ToDoControllerTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int localServerPort;

    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .rootUri("http://localhost:" + localServerPort));
    }

    @Test
    void when_adding_one_item_then_success() {
        // when
        createToDo(new ToDoItem("Walk the dog"));
        var allItems = fetchAllTodos();

        // then
        assertThat(allItems).hasSize(1);
    }

    @Test
    void when_adding_two_items_then_success() {
        // when
        createToDo(new ToDoItem("Walk the dog"));
        createToDo(new ToDoItem("Clean the kitchen"));

        var allItems = fetchAllTodos();

        // then
        assertThat(allItems).hasSize(2);
    }

    private void createToDo(ToDoItem entity) {
        var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        var response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/todos", new HttpEntity<>(entity, headers), String.class);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(NO_CONTENT);
    }

    private List<ToDoItem> fetchAllTodos() {
        return Arrays.asList(testRestTemplate.getForObject("/todos", ToDoItem[].class));
    }
}
```

And here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>todo-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>To-Do App</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please, help me to understand, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the API using the RESTTemplate it crosses the boundary of the local transaction management and becomes as distributed transaction. There is not mechanism available for spring to roll back that call to the rest API. Although in your example the target system is the same application, it need not be so. It could be an external application that is not aware of the transactional boundaries that you have set in your test.